# Bootstrap 3 fieldsets overflow well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap 3 page that displays two fieldsets, arranged side-by-side. These are supposed to be surrounded by a well.

I have found that I need to add a `<div style='clear:both;'></div>` below the last fieldset, otherwise the height of the well will only be one on line. This will cause both fieldsets to overflow out of the bottom of the well.

```
... Above well ...
<div class="well">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset class="col-sm-6">
            <legend>Form 1</legend>
            <div class="form-group">Form Group 1</div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="col-sm-6">
            <legend>Form 2</legend>
            <div class="form-group">Form Group 2</div>
        </fieldset>

        <div style='clear:both;'></div>

    </div>
</div>
... Below well ...
```

I pretty sure I'm missing something here. Is there a better approach to fixing the well?

**Update:**

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmVFy/) of the code that doesn't work. I'd like to know how to make the well surround both fieldsets without having to add the "clear:both" style.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of your code, can you explain what the problem is here? http://jsfiddle.net/rAQfE/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your `col-sm-6` columns in a row like so.

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset class="col-sm-6">
                <legend>Form 1</legend>
                <div class="form-group">Form Group 1</div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="col-sm-6">
                <legend>Form 2</legend>
                <div class="form-group">Form Group 2</div>
            </fieldset>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XmVFy/4/